# Why appending text to field replace all with 0

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 $invoice_id = $data['invoice_id'];
        $remark = '  ### Manually set as Paid Note: '.$data['paid_note'].' ###';
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_invoice SET payment_status = 1, remark = remark+'$remark' WHERE invoice_id = $invoice_id";
```

This should append 'remark' field with new value. but remark field is updated with '0'. Strange! Can't find out whats problem is going on my code. Any idea?

N.B: I am using MySql DBMS.

Comment: I am using MySql DBMS.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat.  I think that you are "adding" two strings, which will return an integer result of `0`?  I'm not sure how MySQL handles boxing, but I imagine it will end up with a "0" as a string?

Comment: Sorry, that link was meant to be to the MySQL `CONCAT` function, which is how MySQL handles string concatenation.  In most other DBMSs you can use `+` or `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn to use parameters.  But your issue is using `+`, which is addition.  I presume you want string concatenation:

```
UPDATE tbl_invoice
    SET payment_status = 1,
        remark = CONCAT(remark, '$remark')
    WHERE invoice_id = $invoice_id;
```

However, the code should look more like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_invoice
    SET payment_status = 1,
        remark = CONCAT(remark, ?)
    WHERE invoice_id = ?;
```

where `?` is a placeholder for the parameters.